# spring dat jpa batch update using repository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data jpa repository to handle my sql-server database, Now my problem is how to batch update to my table, because My table-java bean not contains all the columns from the table, so if I do repository.save(List<>), it may overwrite all the other columns to default value if they are not mapped in my java bean, so now, i just write like below to write native sql to update each column:
[image]

So how to batch update some fields?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a JPA entity object, you would have had to fetch it first.  Once all the objects are fetched then you can update just the properties you want and save the `List<Zip>` in batch.  This will only change the database columns that you specifically change.